# Adding a button subform from mainform in runtime

Tags: c#, button, controls

how can I add a new button in through flawlayoutpanel from another form at runtime

```
   private void btnNotEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YeniForm yeniForm = new YeniForm();
        Button btn = new Button();
        yeniForm.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
```

button doesn't exist in yeni form. Should I do flawlayoutpanel public?

Comment: How about adding `this.Controls.Add(yeniForm);`!?

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't exists on `YeniForm` if you didn't call `yeniForm.Show()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Making `flawLayoutPanel` being `public` you expose *implementation details* which is a *bad practice*. I suggest moving `Button` creating code into `YeniForm`:

```
    public partial class YeniForm : Form {
      ...
      // Let's generalize the implementation and allow to create a control, 
      // not neccesary button
      public T CreateFlawControl<T>() where T : Control, new() {
        T result = new T() {
          Parent = flawLayoutPanel,  
        };

        //TODO : set Size, Location etc here

        return result; 
      }
    }
```

And you can use it as

```
    private void btnNotEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       YeniForm yeniForm = new YeniForm();
       Button btn = yeniForm.CreateFlawControl<Button>();
       ... 
       // do not forget to show the form - yeniForm.Show() or yeniForm.ShowDialog()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create method in `YeniForm` for adding Buttons/Controls and implement adding in the form:

```
class YeniForm : Form
{
    ...
    public void AddButton(Button btn)
    {
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn); // or whatever you need. Calc position for new control, add it to some kind of container (Panel/TableLayoutPanel etc)
    }
}

private void btnNotEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YeniForm yeniForm = new YeniForm();
    Button btn = new Button();
    yeniForm.AddButton(btn);
    ...
}
```